# how i doing deploy django app to vercel when i get this error

Tags: python, django, frameworks, vercel

I've been stuck for a few days when I try to deploy my django app through the vercel.
And vercel give the  syntax error.

```
Failed to run "pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt"
Error: Command failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [35 lines of output]
      /tmp/pip-build-env-cc0ii6jl/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
      
              By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.
      
              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
      running egg_info
      writing psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      
      Error: pg_config executable not found.
      
      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:
      
          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
      
      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
      
      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

this part of my **requirements.txt**

psycopg-binary==3.1.9
psycopg2==2.9.6

i done for installing the psycopg

anyone can tell me how to fix the error please?! Should i create file setup.cfg or is there anything i missed

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue: I believe you should install either psycopg2 or psycopg-binary, but not both, with the 'binary' version recommended for those unfamiliar with it's use & configuration.

Found this info here: [PostgreSQL Python Libraries](https://pysql.tecladocode.com/section05/lectures/04_psycopg2_vs_psycopg2-binary/)

Once I switched to psycopg-binary, my site successfully deployed.

Comment: Sure, i try and that work. and the problem i have is on the env and ENGINE of database. iam using third party(railways). 

and so uding django environ for connect the database, and have solved the problem from people creating tutorial on here: 
https://stackpython.medium.com/how-to-start-django-project-with-a-database-postgresql-aaa1d74659d8